# mod_rewrite issue, possibily with server configuration?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example/? test.php
```

When I hit www.example.com/example I gives me the following:

The requested URL /m/f/example.com/public/test.php was not found on this server.

I have checked that the module is installed and it seems to be doing something, but won't display the file correctly. Public is where all the files of the site are and the test.php is there as well.

Comment: In which directoy is your htaccess file located? And in which directory is your test.php file?

Comment: Both in the same directory, public which is the root directory for the site (containers all files, folders etc)

Comment: Is there a way I can use DirectoryIndex or similar to specify the base URL, as the rewrite appears to be working but the server is looking at a strange location prior to the root (public)...

Comment: yes, I can hit test.php without issue, only when I try pretty up the URL it gives me this error.

Comment: You may need a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). Add the line `RewriteBase /`

Comment: $ after ? makes no difference. If I change it to appear like this (RewriteRule ^example/? http://www.example.com/test.php) and hit /example it redirects to /test.php, as I said, as this point I'm guessing it's something to do with the base URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).

Add the line:

```
RewriteBase /
```